# Apply Lipschitz condition to prove a condition on the coefficients of the exponential Fourier series of f

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwlEw.png)

Question as in the image

note: I have been following Postol's Mathematical Analysis. I used the def to get integral formula for $$c_k=\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\cdot e^{-ikx}$$, and got another formula of $$c_k=e^{-i\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{k}}^{2\pi-\frac{\pi}{k}}f(t+\frac{\pi}{k})\cdot e^{-ikt}$$ using the change of variable hint. Now, I am supposed to get the average of these two formulas, and somehow apply the above Lipschitz condition to prove. (I got stuck at this step)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{k}}^{2\pi-\frac{\pi}{k}}f(\frac{\pi}{k})\cdot e^{-ikt}=0$$ so $$c_k=e^{-i\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{k}}^{2\pi-\frac{\pi}{k}}[f(t+\frac{\pi} k)-f(\frac {\pi} {k})]\cdot e^{-ikt}.$$  Now apply Lipschitz condition and integrate.

Comment: Hi, can you please make some comments on how to get the hint part.

Comment: @mathlad There was a typo. Hope it  is clear now.

Comment: sorry, it 's still not very obvious for me, why it is equal to 0?

Comment: $f(\frac {\pi} k)$ is a constant at. Pull it out and calculate the integral.

Comment: yes, thank you.